# reloadData() doesn't update parent TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a custom `TableViewController` called `LibraryTableViewController`.

```
class LibraryTableViewController: UITableViewController {
```

contains this data for rendering.

> var items: [item] = []

Then, I have another class for Firebase that inherits the `LibraryTableViewController` as a delegate. (I am not sure if this is the right description.)

```
class FirebaseDB : LibraryTableViewController {
```

Then, I have a global instance of FirebaseDB as

> let database = FirebaseDB()

I have an observer listening to the changes in the database in the Firebase class, and I was updating

> self.items

Then, trying to refresh the `LibraryTableViewController` using

> self.tableView.reloadData()

I might be wrong in understanding my current problem. What I think is that the items array that I am updating isn't the same instance as the `tableView` that I see on the app. It is updating the FirebaseDB instance database's items which isn't being rendered on the app. How do I make sure that the right instance is being updated?

Comment: Make sure you update your "items" array and that your self.tableView.reloadData function actually happens. You can put something like print("Ok") next to your reloadData func.

Comment: It does update the "items" array. LibraryTableViewController actually has a items didSet that prints out what is being assigned. It does print out what is being assigned from Firebase as well as what is on the view. There are two "items" basically; I just want one from LibraryTableViewController to be updating.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of code missing 
but you can check:

1. thread must be main, maybe you call from background
2. check is the items is changed 
   the numbers for you
3. check is the tableview not nil
4. check your delegate maybe its also nil

but better give us more code)